# User unable to change Library Permissions

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-foundation

I have a user that is part of a permission group that i want to be able to alter library/list permission.  The permission group was assigned a custom permission level (Permissions Administrator) that has the following permissions selected

```
List Permissions
View Items, Open Items, View Versions

Site Permissions
Manage Permissions, Create Groups, Browse Directories, View Pages, Enumerate Permissions, Browse User Inofrmation, Open
```

Unfortunately the Library Permissions button is grayed out under the Library tab of the Library tools.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Manage Permission is required to tweak @ Site Level, I think "**Manage Lists** also has to be given

Answer (score 1):

I believe the group permission needs to include Manage Lists as well.